# How to host private files on github and link them in public html website?

Tags: javascript, html, github, web-hosting

i made a web game with html, css, javascript and published it in blogger.com but the problem is that anyone can open inspector and copy my code. how to make private files in github, and link them in my html, for example script.js, and so that users will not be able to copy or see the code of my script.js file through inspector, but that the game will still work fine and be public?

i tried to link the github script.js private file with the game logic in it in the html public website game, i didnt expect it to work, and it didnt

Comment: all client-side JS will be visible to the user. generally bundled/processed code is very difficult to parse, but you cannot hide what you make another user's browser perform. *server-side* JS (hopefully) only exposes what you want it to expose.

Comment: The best you can do is heavy obfuscation, so someone taking your code can't (easily) comprehend it.